# Android - open Chrome custom tab instead of launch web browser PublisherAdView

Tags: android, banner-ads

I have been searching the web for finding a way of disabling the on-click for a PublisherAdView but to no avail. We are using DFP for ads https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/quick-start. When a user clicks the ad in the app, the DFP SDK opens a web browser. However, I would like to open a Chrome custom tab instead of launching a web browser. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I know its a little late, but here is a way I was able to solve this.

[PublisherAdView](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/doubleclick/PublisherAdView#public-method-summary) does not expose any methods to accomplish this. One way to accomplish this us to use custom events.

The idea is to fire a custom event on the DFP side when users click on your ad and capture it using [AppEventListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/doubleclick/AppEventListener) on your android app.

on DFP you would set up your template or style like this:

```
<script src="//media.admob.com/api/v1/google_mobile_app_ads.js"></script>
<script>
    handleClick = function() {
      admob.events.dispatchAppEvent("destinationUrl", "%%DEST_URL%%");
    };
  </script>
<div onClick="handleClick()"> ...ad template here... </div>
```

And then on your Android app, add an [AppEventListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/doubleclick/AppEventListener) to capture the event:

```
private static final String DFP_DESTINATION_URL = "destinationUrl";

...

PublisherAdView publisherAdView = new PublisherAdView(getActivity());
publisherAdView.setAppEventListener((eventName, eventValue) -> { // or use publisherAdView.setAppEventListener(new AppEventListener() {...});  if you don't use lambdas
    if (DFP_DESTINATION_URL.equals(eventName)) {
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        /// setup your intent as needed
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
        /// And finally open the custom chrome tab
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(eventValue));
    }
});
publisherAdView.loadAd(mPublisherAdRequest);
```

Hope this helps or points you on the right direction to solve your problem.